# Remove element with foreach [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I need to remove element with Angular foreach, something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.notys, function (value, key) {
    if(value.id === data.id) value.splice(key,1);
});
```

so if this true `value.id === data.id` I need to delete that element form `$scope.notys`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` is not very good for removing elements. Instead consider [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
$scope.notys = $scope.notys.filter(function (value, key) {
    return value.id !== data.id;
});
```

Comment: I know but I didn't know any other solution. I was looking for it... Thanks !